# Identifying the number of rows within a specific value range using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to determine the total number of rows within a specific number range using PHP.

I have a simple MySQL table with a single column. The column contains thousands of rows, each row containing a number between 0 and 100.

I figured out how to find the number of rows for a specific number, using array_count_values, but I can't figure out how to find the number of rows for a range.

For example, how many numbers are there between 60 and 80?

Here is the code that I put together to find a single value. What code should I add to find range values?

```
$query = "SELECT numbers FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error in $query");
$types = array();
while(($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $types[] = $row['numbers'];
}
$counts = array_count_values($types);
echo $counts['12'];
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just count returned number of the executed query ? ie: SELECT *** WHERE between 60/80 ?

Comment: Because I would like the values for 0 to 20, 20 to 40, 40 to 60, 60 to 80 and 80 to 100. So, as I understand I would have to make 5 queries, instead of 1.

Comment: You can use `UNION`

Comment: Hi Dan, Can you tell me more about UNION?

Comment: `UNION` and `UNION ALL` allows you to chain more than one `SELECT` statement together as long as the number of rows returned are the same. So you could add a statement for every range; e.g: `SELECT COUNT(numbers) AS c, '0-20' AS r FROM table WHERE numbers BETWEEN 0 AND 20
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(numbers) AS c, '21-40' AS r FROM table WHERE numbers BETWEEN 21 AND 40` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I was just playing around with UNION suggestion and it works perfectly - thank you.

Comment: Some good answers to your question. Don't forget to upvote and choose one as correct :) And, for completeness, if you ever want to group numbers purely in PHP, here's a function that might help: https://eval.in/789339

Comment: Darragh, Thank you so much for the code. It's a little advanced for me at this time, but I think I'll figure it our over time. I am new to stackflow and to programming altogether, so I don't have enough points to upvote quite yet, but when I do I'll return and this page and do so. Thank you for your help. This site is incredible.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to count within multiple ranges you can use `UNION` so you don't have to send 5 queries.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(numbers) FROM `table` WHERE numbers between 00 and 20
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNT(numbers) FROM `table` WHERE numbers between 20 and 40
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNT(numbers) FROM `table` WHERE numbers between 40 and 60
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNT(numbers) FROM `table` WHERE numbers between 60 and 80
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNT(numbers) FROM `table` WHERE numbers between 80 and 100";
```

Comment: You will need to use `UNION ALL` because if more than one query returns the same count only one value will be returned to represent all results.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this several ways.

## Simple way (one full table scan)

```
SELECT SUM(IF(x BETWEEN 20 AND 30, 1, 0)) AS b_20_30,
       SUM(...) AS b_31_40,
       ...
FROM tableName...
```

will return only one row with all your results in the time of a table scan.

## Fancy way (*not really recommended*)

If you can come up with a *rule* to map your intervals to a single number, for example:

```
 0...9   => interval i = 0
10...19  => interval i = 1   => the rule is "i = FLOOR(X/10)"
20...29  => interval i = 2
```

...and you don't need to scan too many rows, you might do something **not very maintainable** like this:

```
SELECT SUM(FLOOR(POW(100, FLOOR(x / 10)))) AS result FROM tableName;
```

Here, a value of 25 (between 20 and 29) will become 2, and the total sum will be increased by 100<sup>2</sup>. So long as you never have more than 100 rows in each group, the final result will be a univocal sum of powers and, if you have - say - 17 rows between 0 and 9, 31 rows between 10 and 19, and 74 between 20 and 29, you'll get a "magical parlor trick" answer of

```
743117
```

from whence you can recover the number of rows as 74,31,17 in that order.

Using 1000 instead of 100 would yield 74031017 (and the possibility of coping with up to 999 numbers in each group).

Note that the use of functions inside the SELECT pretty much guarantees you'll need a full, slow table scan.

## Using indexes for speed

But we can get rid of the table scan, and simplify generation, by judiciously using indexed WHEREs - this is identical, performance-wise, to a UNION, but the result is simpler since it is only one row:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE x BETWEEN ...) AS b_20_30,
       (...)
; -- no table name on the outer query
```

This will need several subqueries (one per interval), but those subqueries will all use an index on `x` where available, which can make the overall query very fast. You just need

```
 CREATE INDEX x_ndx ON tableName(x);
```

The same index will greatly improve the performance of the "simple" query above, which will no longer need a table scan but only a much faster index scan.

## Build the query using PHP

Supposing we have the intervals specified as convenient arrays, we can use PHP to generate the query in the first place. No need of manually entering all those SELECTs.

```
$intervals = [ [ 20, 30 ], [ 17, 25 ], ... ];

function queryFromIntervals(array $intervals) {
    $index = 0;
    return 'SELECT ' . 
        implode(',', array_map(
            function($interval) use ($tableName, &$index) {
                return "(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM {$tableName} WHERE x BETWEEN {$interval[0]} AND {$interval[1]}) AS b_" . ($index++);
            },
            $intervals
        ))
        // . ", (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$tableName}) AS total"
        . ';';
    }
```

This will again yield a single row, with fields named `b_0`, `b_1`, and so on. They will contain the number of rows where the value of x is between the bounds of the corresponding interval in `$intervals` (the intervals may overlap).

So by executing the query and retrieving a tuple called `$result`, you might get

```
[ 'b_0' => 133, 'b_1' => 29 ]
```

meaning that there are 133 rows with x between 20 and 30, and 29 with x between 17 and 25. You can add to the query a last total field (commented in the code above):

```
, ... ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName ) AS total;
```

to also get the total number of rows.

The same function, changing the inner `return` value, can be adapted to generate the "simple" query which uses IFs instead of SELECTs.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all of these suggestions. Some of them are a little advanced for me at this time, but I'll work on them. - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the database do the heavy lifting for you?

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE numbers BETWEEN 60 AND 80";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error in $query");
$row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct. Still, I'm trying to figure out how to do this in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - that and UNION is what I should be doing - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you try to put a condition in your request sql.
Look that https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

```
    $query = "SELECT numbers FROM table WHERE numbers >= 60 AND numbers <= 80";
```

Comment: I accept that the query can do the work, but how could I do this using PHP.?

Comment: Can become clearer, you wish to secure the request ?, to know how to connect has a database?

Comment: I understand how to make the query. I'm just wondering how this can be done in PHP with the query I described.